# GetStream Push Notifications 'BadDeviceToken' error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, getstream-io

I followed the following GetStreamIO, react documentation to implement push notifications for an Ionic mobile app. As a start, I was trying this for IOS via APN.
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/push_introduction/

When I tested the implementation through TestFlight, it gives the following error.

> publishing the message failed. code = "400"; error = "BadDeviceToken"

Could anyone help to figure this out or point to an article or documentation that does?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?